# Gearman remove worker function

Tags: php, queue, command-line-interface, gearman, worker

I would like to clean the tested function from my gearman worker. Do you have any idea how can I manage it from CLI or PHP?

Here is the screen shot and for sure you will know which one I would like to remove without gearman server restarting.

http://cl.ly/image/0I3Y3g0A361J

Thanks in advance. Best regards!

Comment: What is the output of `gearadmin --status`? Functions are exclusively tied to workers. Only worker can register or unregister function. On the screenshot provided there are no workers for functions test and test2. It does not sound right. Providing output of `gearadmin --status` would eliminate or point to the error in admin utility you are using.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with *gearadmin --drop-function XXX*